# Matlab fixed point quantizer

Tags: matlab

It seems tricky to use Matlab's fixed point quantizer, probably some hidden parameters. Here is an example:

```
b = fi(pi, 1, 21, 16)   % use total length = 21-bit, fraction = 16-bit
ntBP = numerictype(1, 10, 9)  % quantize to total length = 10-bit, fraction = 9-bit
c = quantize(b, ntBP)   % this returns -0.8594
```

Looks like the problem is matlab didn't take care of the sign bit:

```
bin(b)        % return '000110010010000111111'
bin(c)        % return '1001001000'. This is why the quantizer output is negative
```

The question is, is this the expected way to use the quantizer or not?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You specify a numeric type with a limited range. Values outside the range wrap.

Comment: it's not what I am trying to accomplish but what do the fixed point operators do there. The example showed the intended conversion from (21,16) to (10, 9) is incorrect. There should not be any "wrap" in this operation, not even the sign change in the example.

Comment: Instead of making assumptions about how the software works, and then proclaiming the software has a bug, you should read the documentation and figure out what the software actually does. You specify 10 bits, of which 9 are the fraction. That leaves 1 bit for the integral part of the number. That means that your number is in the range 0<=x<2. But your number is signed, so maybe this is -1<=x<1,  not sure how it is implemented. In either case, if you assign pi there is overflow.